# Include a hash character in URL path via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hash, insert, url-rewriting, pathname

I am trying to insert a hash in the pathname like this:

> mysite.com/specific-page

to

> ```
> mysite.com/#specific-page
> ```

The hash in this URI is not an anchor. It calls AJAX code.

I've tried using the following (individually) in my .htaccess without success:

> ```
> Redirect 301 /specific-page http://www.mysite.com/#specific-page
> ```

and

> ```
> RewriteRule specific-page /#specific-page [R=301,L]
> ```

Of course I have the RewriteEngine on:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

And these additional rules as a part of SEO URL rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(the "www" in line two and three is not there. I had to include it because it wouldn't let me post otherwise)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(specific-page)/?$ /#$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I tried it with and without the parentheses. In IE and FF it appends the #specific-page to specific-page like this /specific-page#specific-page

Comment: Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess?

Comment: In my testing `http://localhost/specific-page` got redirected to `http://localhost/#specific-page`

Comment: Yes, I have the other rules as a part of SEO URL rewrites (it won't let me post them here).

Comment: Please, see my edited original question above. I included my additional rules.

Comment: Ok in that case you need to place this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line and use `www` in your URL to test.

Comment: Hmmm. In the URL field it looks like it's redirecting, but it enters a loop and it never loads (or stop loading). That's when I place your code right after the RewriteBase/

Comment: There should not be any looping. Try commenting your `www` rule and test in a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the question is a good one and I searched even in other posts and there are conflicts in the answers.

This worked for me to redirect from an old contatti.aspx page to the new wordpress version /#contacts including the ash

`RewriteRule ^contatti\.aspx$  /#contacts [R=301,L,NE,NC]`

Hope this helps!